# deleting elements in array of pointer (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers

Suppose I have an array of pointers like

```
Person** p = new Person*[5]
// p is filled with five person pointer (say p[2] = *John where John is an object of person
// now we want to remove p[2]
delete p[2];
p[2] = p[3];
p[3] = p[4];
p[4] = nullptr;
```

The program cannot be compiled unless I remove the line of delete and nullptr.
Why will this happen? If I do not delete p[2], there should be problem as I cannot access john again?

Comment: Post a [MCVE] including all error messages please. How did you instatiate the `Person` instances for that array?

Comment: ***The program cannot be compiled unless I remove the line of delete and nullptr*** Why? If there are errors add them as text to your question. If this is Visual Studio copy the errors from the Output Tab not the Errors List.

Comment: I think about `nullptr` it is the standard of C++ you are using, it should be C++11 to use `nullptr`

Comment: OH,  You seem to have forgotten a semi-colon in the first line, this is why C++ couldn't recognize your `delete` as another statement, this I couldn't know without trying to run on an online IDE

Comment: Don't use new and delete and arrays, use smart pointers and std::vector.

Comment: I think the forgotten semicolon is just a typo in the example code. I voted to close the question because the example code is not enough to give a good answer.

Comment: I think it should be the problem from a online compiler. When I use eclipse and test it again, it works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please use `std::list` (or `std::vector`) if you have this kind of patterns. The standard containers will be better than most solutions you will come up with.

Comment: Preferably `std::vector` before `std::list`. But in general I am not a friend of answering _off-topic_ questions.

Comment: Also he can use `shared_ptr`, in modern C++ you shouldn't use `delete`, and you shouldn't use `new` except inside a smart pointer creation (`unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

For `nullptr` to work, you have to compile with the option `--std=c++11`, because it is a keyword from C++11, like `auto` and the lambda expression syntax.

`gcc yourfile.cpp --std=c++11`

But about the `delete`, it is just a forgotten semi-colon on the first line.

C/C++ requires semi-colons to separate statements.

You should write something like that:

```
Person** p = new Person*[5]; // A semi-colon was forgotten here.
// p is filled with five person pointer (say p[2] = *John where John is an object of person
// now we want to remove p[2]
delete p[2];
p[2] = p[3];
p[3] = p[4];
p[4] = nullptr;
```

Also if you don't want to compile for `--std=c++11`, try using `0` or `NULL` instead of `nullptr`.

```
p[4] = NULL;
```